# If $A$ is Lebesgue measurable then there exist $F_1\subset F_2\subset\dots$ closed in $A$ such that $|A\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if it is correct and/or/if it could be improved somehow, thanks.

"If $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, then there exists an increasing sequence $F_1\subset F_2\subset\dots$ of closed sets in $A$ such that $|A\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n|=0$"

My proof:

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set: then we know that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a closed set $C\subset A$ such that $|A\setminus C|<\varepsilon$, so, for every $n\geq 1$, we have that there exists $C_n\subset A$ closed such that $|A\setminus C_n|<\frac{1}{n}$. Consider now, for $n\geq 1$, the sets $F_n$ defined by $F_n:=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}C_k$: these form an increasing sequence of sets ($F_{n+1}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}C_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}C_k \cup C_{n+1}=F_n\cup C_{n+1}\supset F_n$) which are also closed (being the union of *finitely* many closed sets). Now, since $A\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\subset A\setminus F_k\subset A\setminus C_k$ for every $k\geq 1$ we have as a consequence that $|A\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n|\leq |A\setminus F_k|\leq |A\setminus C_k|<\frac{1}{k}$ for every $k\geq 1$ so $|A\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n|=0$, and this concludes the proof. $\square$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your prove simply relies on finite unions of closed sets being closed.

You can even claim $F_i$ compact!

The general proof would be:

Since $A$ is measureable there exists a sequence of $A_n\subset A$ compact so that $\mathcal L^N(\bigcup A_n) = \mathcal L^N(A)$. By setting $F_n = \bigcup_{k\leq n} A_n$ we get $F_n$ compact and clearly
$\mathcal L^N(\bigcup F_n) = \mathcal L^N(A)$.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question; it seems to me that I have only used the definition of Lebesgue measurable set "a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable if there exists a Borel set $B\subset A$ such that $|A\setminus B|=0$" and the fact that "$A$ is Lebesgue measurable iff $\forall\varepsilon>0$ there exists $C\subset A$ closed such that $|A\setminus C|<\varepsilon$". Could you please point out a counterexample where my proof fails? Thanks

Comment: Then there is no problem. I somewhat missinterpreted what premises you used. I removed that remark.